# Scanning values in text files and output result in a console in c#

Tags: c#, io

I am trying to read values in txt files and output results maximum 250 lines only (note that there could be more or less values in that txt file).

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    readLine = reader.ReadLine();
    if (readLine != null)
    {
        // read first line
        //do some arithmetic etc... in those values
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++){                    
            if (numbers[i] != 0)
            {
                // display the number + space
                Console.Write(numbers[i] + " ");
                allValues.Add(numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

The problem is that it seems like I am outputting a matrix which has more/less rows than it should. Could anyone advice me on how to output them withing a maximum of 250 lines? Its already has 14 rows. Just the columns need to be 250.

Answer (score 0):

So in your code you can count number of lines you read and if count exceeds 250 end the while loop.

```
int count = 0;
while (!reader.EndOfStream && count <= 250)
{
   readLine = reader.ReadLine();
   if (readLine != null)
   {
      // read first line
      //do some arithmetic etc... in those values
      count++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and simpliest way:

```
string line = string.Empty;
for(int i = 0; i < 250 && (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null; i++) {
    // your code
}
```